# HTTP Bad Request with openfire MUC service

Tags: http, openfire, bad-request

Here is my code

```
$xml_data ='<chatRoom>
        <broadcastPresenceRoles>
            <broadcastPresenceRole>moderator</broadcastPresenceRole>
            <broadcastPresenceRole>participant</broadcastPresenceRole>
            <broadcastPresenceRole>visitor</broadcastPresenceRole>
    </broadcastPresenceRoles>
    <canAnyoneDiscoverJID>false</canAnyoneDiscoverJID>
    <canChangeNickname>false</canChangeNickname>
    <canOccupantsChangeSubject>false</canOccupantsChangeSubject>
    <canOccupantsInvite>false</canOccupantsInvite>
    <creationDate>2014-02-12T15:52:37.592+01:00</creationDate>
    <description>Global Chat Room</description>
    <logEnabled>true</logEnabled>
    <loginRestrictedToNickname>false</loginRestrictedToNickname>
    <maxUsers>30</maxUsers>
    <membersOnly>false</membersOnly>
    <moderated>false</moderated>
    <naturalName>global-1</naturalName>
    <owners>
        <owner>admin@localhost</owner>
    </owners>
    <password>test</password>
    <persistent>true</persistent>
    <publicRoom>true</publicRoom>
    <registrationEnabled>false</registrationEnabled>
    <roomName>global</roomName>
</chatRoom>';

 $opts = array('http' =>
         array(
           'method'  => 'POST',
           'header'  => "Content-Type: text/xml",//\r\n".
           "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("admin:admin"),//."\r\n",
           'timeout' => 60
          )
     );

 `$URL = 'http://localhost:9090/plugins/mucservice/chatrooms'`;

        $ch = curl_init($URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml', "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("admin:admin")."\r\n"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        echo 'Code : '.$code;
        print_r($output);           
        curl_close($ch);
```

With this code , I am sending post request to openfire muc plugin with xml data and authorization headers as this readme file suggested me to do [ https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/mucservice/readme.html] .. It says bad request 400 .

Openfire Logs are

```
            2014.07.18 11:04:26 org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginServlet - 14 
        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14 
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseBase64Binary(Unknown Source) 
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.parseBase64Binary(Unknown Source) 
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(Unknown Source) 
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.servlet.BasicAuth.decode(BasicAuth.java:18) 
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.servlet.AuthFilter.filter(AuthFilter.java:39) 
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1527) 
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) 
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) 
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) 
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) 
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540) 
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) 
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginServlet.handleServlet(PluginServlet.java:316) 
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginServlet.service(PluginServlet.java:111) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:547) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1359) 
        at org.jivesoftware.admin.PluginFilter.doFilter(PluginFilter.java:78) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330) 
        at org.jivesoftware.admin.AuthCheckFilter.doFilter(AuthCheckFilter.java:164) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330) 
        at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118) 
        at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:478) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:941) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:409) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:875) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:441) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:919) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:582) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source
```

I am stuck with this thing since long time.. Kindly help me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I've posted openfire logs here in my question.. Kindly help me if anything can be resolved by this log.

Comment: looks like it can't decode your basic authorization header - dig in that direction

Comment: it works with same authentication header in another GET request and Content Type : text/xml .. So How should I proceed further ?

Comment: I'd recommend to use one of xmpp client libraries - it will handle all that low-level moments for you

Comment: I am trying to create room in openfire .. and xmpp library for php does not provide assistance to create room :( 

Kindly let me know if I am mistaken

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Content Type to "Content-Type: application/xml" not "Content Type : text/xml". The Content Type : text/xml works if you GET something, but by PUT and POST you need to set "Content-Type: application/xml".

Another possible problem is follow line:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml', "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("admin:admin")."\r\n"));
```

Try to change it to:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', 'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode("admin:admin")));
```